# Gitlab Trigger API returns 404

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I created a trigger (using settings/ci_cd page). The instructions below the trigger tell me to call it using version 3 API (of course, I set the token variable to the token stated under the trigger section):

```
curl -X POST \
     -F token=${TOKEN} \
     -F ref=master \
     https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/2313008/trigger/builds
```

Which only returns:

> {"error":"404 Not Found"}

I also tried to follow the [API v4 documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/):

```
curl --request POST \
     --form token=${TOKEN} \
     --form ref=master \
     https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/2313008/trigger/pipeline
```

which returns the same error.

Are there any additional settings required?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the token variable?

Comment: Yes, I am. Also I would expect to get some other Error then 404.

Comment: Well, 404 is pretty clever taken you don't want someone to enumerate the projects you have on your machine.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue, but I was using `Personal Access Token` instead of `Pipeline trigger token`!!

You can generate this token inside your project repo CI/CD settings.
[image: Pipeline triggers]

Answer (score 0):

I retried the same request today, now it works. Probably there has been some problem with the gitlab.com.